# Find Id of NMOS

Tags: transistors, mosfet, nmos

[image: NMOS]

I need to find the drain current in the above circuit where I also know \$V_{TH} = 1\,\mathrm{V}\$ and \$\mu_{n}C_{ox} = 2\cdot 10^{-4} \frac{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{V}^2}\$.  I'm just not sure about how to find \$V_{GS}\$ in this circuit.  I'm used to using voltage dividers.

Comment: As a heads-up, when a transistor is connected in this fashion, it is said to be called "diode-connected."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the gate source and drain connected so MOSFET is in saturation so we can write:(Be aware that gate current is zero and current of drain is current that pass resistor so we can write I=v/R that I is current of drain and V is Voltage of gate)
[image]

SO we can obtain V from this equation and then obtain current of drain.
(Sorry for my bad English)